# Can Crossover 20 replace Wine64 to build Windows apps using Electron 11.x.x on Apple silicon (M1)

Tags: electron, quasar, apple-m1, crossover

I am working on a cross platform Quasar Framework app and recently moved to a Mac Air M1.

As per Electron, when Electron 11.0.0 was released it included support for Apple silicon.

But Wine64 is not supported on M1.  And so using Electron I cannot build a Windows app.

Does anybody have any experience with building Windows apps using Electron?  Anybody successfully used Crossover 20 in lieu of Wine64?  If yes to any of these questions, would you know the Electron and Crossover settings needed for a build?